# Nested Dict to Table in Jinja2

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I am scratching my head trying to correctly format a table from a nested dict in Jinja2, but having no luck.

The dict is something like this:

```
dict = {
    key_1: {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3},
    key_2: {a: 11, b: 12, c: 13},
}
```

And I want the table to look like:

```
| key_1      | key_2        |
| ---------- | ------------ |
| a | b | c  | a  | b  | c  |
| ---------- | ------------ |
| 1 | 2 | 3  | 11 | 12 | 13 |
```

The closest I have come is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        {% for k1 in dict.keys() %}
        <td>{{ k1 }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        {% for k2, value in dict[k1].items() %}
        <td> {{ k2 }} </td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        {% for k2, value in dict[k1].items() %}
        <td> {{ value }} </td>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
```

But this doesn't work. I am having trouble assigning the k1 variable without also having to extend the loop in a way that ruins the layout of the table. I would rather not have to rearrange the dict or split it into several dicts.

Can I convert a dict like the one I have to a table of that structure in Jinja2? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not test my solution, there might be typos, but main points are:

- `colspan` for proper formatting
- nested loops (inner and outer dict)

(`dict` should not be used as a variable name, renamed to`dct`.)

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            {% for k, d2 in dct.items() %}
                <td colspan="{{ d2|length }}">{{ k }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        <tr>
            {% for d2 in dct.values() %}
                {% for k2 in d2 %}
                    <td>{{ k2 }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        <tr>
            {% for d2 in dct.values() %}
                {% for v2 in d2.values() %}
                    <td>{{ v2 }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </table>
```